# Asp.net web api : redirect unauthorized requst to forbidden page

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, authorization, identity

im trying to redirect unauthorized request to some forbidden page but instead i'm getting forbidden page in response body , how can i fix this ?

Here's my StartUp class :

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext(StoreContext.Create);
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
     AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
     ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(30),
});

app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);
```

The method which im trying to reach is :

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public string GetCurrentUsername()
    {
        return UserManager.FindByEmail(User.Identity.Name).Name;
    }
```

i have tried this things :

- remove LoginPath from cookieOptions to return 401
- create custom authorize attribute

by the way im using Angular , i think this issue is related to ajax call ...

Comment: did you check my answer below?

Answer (score 0):

you can extend the authorize attribute to specify the forbidden page.
something like this:

Add a new class named AuthorizationAttribute  which inherits from the AuthorizeAttribute class. and then override the 2 methods

```
public class AuthorizationAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
   protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
   {
      //check if user in in role admin and if yes then return true, else return false. Once it returns false, then HandleUnauthorizedRequest will be triggered automatically
      return userManager.IsUserInAdminRole(username);
   }

   protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
   {
      filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Error/ForbiddenPage");
   }
}
```

And in your method, use the new AuthorizationAttribute class:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorization] //You can just write Authorization without the word Attribute
    public string GetCurrentUsername()
    {
        return UserManager.FindByEmail(User.Identity.Name).Name;
    }
```

If it is related to your ajax, you find here: [github.com/ronnieoverby/mvc-ajax-auth](https://github.com/ronnieoverby/mvc-ajax-auth) 
a similar problem with solution

Comment: i've checked that before and it didnt worked for me :(

Comment: see this link github.com/ronnieoverby/mvc-ajax-auth

Comment: you are doing an ajax call, so at the end it is the same principle :)!!

Comment: yeah i know and it's kind of weird why it doesnt work ... if i try to access some unauthorized page , html will show up with no data and if i reload the page then forbidden page will show up . im trying to resolve this for hours but cant !!!

Comment: so you mean, you are getting redirected to the html page correctly, but the content of the forbidden page, is appearing only after you refresh. right?

Comment: yeah that's it.

Comment: ok. can you tell me what url you have when you see the html pagw without content, and what url you have when you refresh?

Comment: before reload : my admin panel index url which is http://localhost:49388/#!/Panel/WareList

Comment: after reload : the same url with forbbiden page content

Comment: nope . by the way app is combination of mvc and api